# DocuSign From Demo to Live

Tags: php, api, docusignapi

Hope you are good.

My docusign is working fine on my demo environment . However when I put it on live . I keep getting this error. I am pretty sure that my credentials are all correct.

```
{ "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED", "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid." }
```

Please see my code below:

```
$url = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123456/envelopes";
  $urlAuth = array(
        "Username"=>"xxx@nexxxxger.com.",
        "Password"=>"xxxxxx",
        "IntegratorKey"=>"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
);
```

I also trie the below url:

```
$url = "https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123456/envelopes";

$url = "https://eu.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123456/envelopes";
```

But no good .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of guessing which server your account is on, you need to make an API call to have DocuSign tell you your base URL.

If you're using Legacy Header auth (tsk tsk), you should make a GET call to https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information and check the Base URL in the response.

If you're using the Account Server / OAuth, you'll need to make a User Info call as documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints